# What is the standard way to stop random elements showing before the script loads?

Tags: javascript, html

When my site loads, for a very short, but noticable time, all of the elements on my page appear in their default position based on their placement in my HTML and CSS. After this the JavaScript file is loaded and everything moves into it's correct position based on google maps api, bootstrap etc.

What is the standard way to stop elements from being visible until after the script has placed them in the correct place?

Comment: Maybe put the CSS at the top with `display:none`, then make the container visible with the JS?

Comment: Please provide a simplified example where this happens. The problem often is that such JS libraries read out the *current* position of the element (after the document rendering is completed) in order to determine their *new* position and size.

Comment: @trincot one example would be that the legend and location search box aren't applied as controls of the google map until after the script has loaded. So they kind of just sit on the page until the script puts them on the map.

Comment: In that case you should hide them with CSS and find out how you can listen to the change that should trigger those boxes to become visible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd go with something like this.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style = "";
  }, 100);
};
```

```html
<body style="display: none;">
  Your whole page goes here.
</body>
```

This hides the whole page for up to 100 ms AFTER you've completed page loading. 100 ms should be enough to render at least once the page, which will position everything on it, unless it's more complex than that and requires more attention.

Comment: This seemed to work well enough for my use case. Not sure why someone voted it down, Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively you can have `<body style="visible: hidden;">` and/or increase the timeout. Consider that on very slow machines (phones) the timeout may not suffice. That's why this solution was downvoted. You can't really have a fixed timeout and should instead use an event signalling when the placement has been completed. But this second, correct, approach requires you to find those events and "collect" them in a promise, much like an `AND` expression: place legend AND place search box AND whatever else must be placed. But if this solution suffices, you're better off with it: quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display property of your main wrapper to none. Then using the "on load" event, set the display to block.
You can also show a preloader while page is loading, and hide it when the page has finished loading.

```js
//if you have images:
$(document).on("load", () => {
  $(".wrapper").show();
});

//if you don't have many images:
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".wrapper").show();
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper" style="display: none">
  <p>The content goes here</p>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```